# How to get this type of font on latex code?

Tags: fonts

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to both the highlighted fonts/formats onto my latex document from my Professor's on those specific words/paragraph. How would I go about doing so? Thanks!

Comment: it's monospace (teletype) so you can use `\texttt{generateOneData()}` for inline and `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` for the block

Comment: Thankyou so much! It worked great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's monospace (teletype) so you can use `\texttt{generateOneData()}` for inline and

```
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
```

for the block

Comment: To expand on what David said, if you want special characters in line, there's a command `\verb` which uses a special syntax—the first non-space character after `\verb` will be treated as a delimiter and everything up to the next occurrence of that character will be printed exactly as input, including space. No newlines are allowed and `\verb` cannot be used in the argument to any other command.